# AppWidgets - Updating Intent extras contents dynamically

Tags: android, android-intent, android-appwidget, android-pendingintent

I have an `AppWidget` that interacts with two `Activities`. First `Activity` asks user to type in some text. Here's the code to start this `Activity` from `AppWidget`:

```
Intent promptIntent = new Intent(context,
        TransparentPromptActivity.class);
promptIntent.putExtra("appwidget_id", appWidgetId);
promptIntent.putExtra("message", incomingMessage);
PendingIntent promptPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context, 0, promptIntent, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.app_widget_tv,
        promptPendingIntent);
```

This `Activity` sends the entered message back to the `AppWidge`t which displays it. Then there's an `Activity` that shares the message, and here's the code to start this `Activity`:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
shareIntent.putExtra("message", incomingMessage);
PendingIntent sharePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context, 0, shareIntent, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.app_widget_btn_share,
        sharePendingIntent);
```

As you can see, the message is stored in a local `incomingMessage` variable. However, when the second `Activity` is started, `incomingMessage` is empty, means the `Intent` contents are not updated when the variable value changes. How this effect can be achieved? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How this effect can be achieved?

Use an appropriate flag on your `getActivity()` call, such as [`FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT), if you are creating a `PendingIntent` on the same core `Intent` (e.g., for the same activity) and are changing extras.

That being said, since `TransparentPromptActivity` and `MainActivity` are not the same activity, `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` will not help. Perhaps your issue is that `incomingMessage` is `null` in your second case.